# Getting Rounded Values in the final result of Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

How can the below linq Query be modified such that i can get a Rounded figure of values.

```
                 var result=GetStudentsWithTheirMarks()                
                .OrderByDescending(x => Math.Round(x.PercentageScore)).Take(5)                 
                .OrderBy(x => x.PercentageScore);
```

Please ignore the presence of two order by clause as this is done for with a purpose. 
GetStudentsWithThierMarks returns Student List with their FirstName and PercentageScore.
I believe in the above query Math.Round is only applicable when during order by operation so final result still contains values in decimal places whereas i am only interested to see rounded figures with integer values. I just cant figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store this value in an anonymous type:

```
var result = GetStudentsWithTheirMarks()    
  .Select(s => new 
  { 
      Student = s, 
      RoundedPercentageScore = Math.Round(s.PercentageScore) 
  })          
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.RoundedPercentageScore )
  .Take(5)                 
  .OrderBy(x => x.Student.PercentageScore);
```

Now you can access it in this way:

```
foreach(var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine("RoundedPercentageScore: " x.RoundedPercentageScore);
```

Comment: Hi Tim Thanks for the response. In the first part OrderByDescending Clause will give syntax error.

Comment: @Sike12: are you sure that you've used the code i've posted above? I don't see the reason for your Syntax Error.

Comment: Apologies. My mistake i had a different return type in my method. so thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You just need a `Select` :

```
var result= GetStudentsWithTheirMarks()                
            .OrderByDescending(x => Math.Round(x.PercentageScore))
            .Take(5)                 
            .OrderBy(x => x.PercentageScore)
            .Select(x => Math.Round(x.PercentageScore));
```

Comment: Hi Selman22 i know thats the syntax but as soon as i put that in my query i have syntax issue with the order by clause could you please post the full query. thanks

Comment: what is the **ERROR**

Comment: Apologies. My mistake i had a different return type in my method. so thanks for your answer